# Multiple indexes in Solr

Tags: mysql, solr

I want to index two tables from MySQL using Apache Solr. Please see my data-config and schema files below.

```
<dataConfig> 
 <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" user="root" password="root" batchSize="1" />  
 <document name="tb_location">   
  <entity name="tb_location" query="SELECT * FROM tb_location">    
   <field column="loc_code" name="id"/>    
   <field column="loc_code" name="loc_code"/>    
   <field column="loc_name" name="loc_name"/> 
   <field column="loc_name" name="loc_name_ci"/> 
   <field column="ADM1_FULL_NAME" name="state"/>         
  </entity>  
 </document>
 <document name="person">   
  <entity name="person" query="SELECT * FROM person">    
   <field column="id" name="personid"/>    
   <field column="fname" name="fname"/>    
   <field column="lname" name="lname"/> 
   <field column="town" name="town"/>       
  </entity>  
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Schema.xml

```
 <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> -
    <field name="loc_code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="loc_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="loc_name_ci" type="string_ci" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="state" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

    <field name="personid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="fname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="lname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="town" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Also i created unique id for each tables (id and personid). But when i execute the dataimport module, nothing is fetched or indexed. Can someone help me to figure out where exactly the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link for Multiple indexes...

[Multiple indexes](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it !!! data-config.xml should be as follows.

```
<dataConfig> 
 <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" user="root" password="root" batchSize="1" />  
 <document name="tb_location">   
  <entity name="tb_location" query="SELECT * FROM tb_location">    
   <field column="loc_code" name="id"/>    
   <field column="loc_code" name="loc_code"/>    
   <field column="loc_name" name="loc_name"/> 
   <field column="loc_name" name="loc_name_ci"/> 
   <field column="ADM1_FULL_NAME" name="state"/>     
  </entity> 
  <entity name="person" query="SELECT * FROM person">    
   <field column="id" name="personid"/>    
   <field column="fname" name="fname"/>    
   <field column="lname" name="lname"/> 
   <field column="town" name="town"/>   
  </entity>  
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```